# How to set a variable to the same amount of space be allocated and pointed to by another pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic

I have an int type variable `i` and a float type pointer `f`.

How can I set `i`  to the same amount of space be allocated and pointed to by `f`?

This is how I define `f`

```
float *f = NULL;
f = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
*f = 30.5;
```

Comment: You can not get the information of the size with only the pointer. Do you know how many elements for `f` were allocated?

Comment: Lets say ‘f’ only store a float number, which is ‘float f = 30.5’.

Comment: i = sizeof(*f);

Comment: @user8314628 but the question says that `f` is a pointer which would be `float *f`. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I modify my question. Does it look more clear? I thought `float f = 30.5` is the same with the version I modified. Maybe it's not. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you asking to create a second block of memory that is equivalent in size with an existing block you have?

Comment: Exactly! Thank you for translating my question.

Comment: For that you need to know the `type` of the other object **and** the number previously allocated. Since you only have a pointer `f` (and not an array), using `sizeof (f)` is simply `sizeof (a_pointer)`. So you must also know how many `float` were previously allocated. (and generally speaking `float` and `int` are both the same size (e.g. 4-bytes each)). The type-size for each will be implementation defined, so if you are on some embedded system, make sure you verify.

Comment: But these are all information that I have so far. The requirement for `f` is allocating space for a single floating point number.

Comment: In your example, you only allocate 1-`float`, so verify `sizeof (float) == sizeof (int)` and then allocate for 1-`int`, e.g. `int *i = malloc (sizeof *i);`

Comment: Still get the error `comparison between pointer and integer`

Comment: @user8314628 There is no comparision in your code, it would be helpful if you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `"comparison between pointer and integer"` is telling you that you have an error in your *level of indirection* where you are comparing a pointer with something not a pointer (an `int`). This is generally caused by a mistake in adding at dereference (e.g. a `'*'`) before a pointer where you shouldn't or failing to use it where you should.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to:

**Edit based on new data from question.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void) {
// your code goes here
    float *f = NULL;
    int *i = NULL;
    void* allocated_space = malloc(sizeof(float) > sizeof(int) ? sizeof(float) : sizeof(int));
    f = (float *)allocated_space;
    i = (int *)allocated_space;
    *f = 30.5;
    free(allocated_space);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this would violate the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Of course. If we want exactly the same size then we must use bitefilds. But I don't understand his question. I'm not English native and he also is not probably.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. This gives an error: `comparison between pointer and integer`

Comment: Your pointer cast violates the *strict alias* rules because a cast of  `int` to `float` violates [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) Technically the cast itself doesn't but any reference of the `int i` through pointer `f` does.

Comment: There's no strict aliasing violation here, the commentors who suggested it are wrong